Are 自分で来ました and 自分で来た grammatical?
Are 自分で来ました and 自分で来た grammatical?
From my understanding, 自分で means "by oneself, relying only on oneself, without any help coming from others" while 一人で is a more neutral term meaning "alone, with no one around".
I tried doing some Google searches to solve an exercise on this topic and got very unexpected results.
"一人で行きました" - over one million results.
"一人で来ました" - over one million results.
"自分で行きました" - nearly two million results.
"自分で来ました" - less than 10 results (?)
I have no idea why 自分で来ました is so asymmetrically rare.
Repeating the search with plain past forms, the asymmetry is still there:
"一人で行った" - 10 million results
"一人で来た" - 2 million results
"自分で行った" - over 15 million results
"自分で来た" - less than 10 results (?)
This asymmetry disappears when I switch to dictionary forms, as all the results are roughly in the same order of magnitude:
"一人で行く" - 15 million results
"一人で来る" - over one million results
"自分で行く" - over 20 million results
"自分で来る" - over two million results
Could you explain what is happening with the past forms?

I'm curious how you got those numbers. My understanding is Google stopped showing search hit counts.

@aguijonazo You still can do it. Here is an example of a query with た未だ: https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=c7afcd4ef85db31a2#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=%22%E3%81%9F%E6%9C%AB%E3%81%A0%22

@aguijonazo The way I do it now is by doing a normal search, then clicking on Tools and the hit count appears

First, Google hit counts are surprisingly unstable and unreliable, and they shouldn't be used even as a rough estimate. By tomorrow, some of those numbers might change by two orders of magnitude. Use a corpus instead.
Next, 自分で in Japanese and "by oneself" in English are different. The former basically means "not someone else but I (do it)". It sometimes also implies "without any help from others" or "alone", but I would say that's not the core meaning of the phrase.

自分でやりました = (Not someone else but) I did it.
自分でやったの? = You did it (although it's supposed to be done by an expert/secretary/etc)?
自分で行きます = (Not you but) I myself will go.

自分で行きます would be far less common than 1人で行きます, despite those hit counts.
And that's why 自分で来ました usually sounds a little puzzling. With the aid of a context, it might be used to mean "I came here on my own will (and not at someone's request)", but it's usually not used to mean "I came here alone" or "I came here without any help".

Thank you! Just like you said, today's hit counts on my browser have completely changed and 自分で来た / 来ました no longer appears to be rare.
Could 自分で来ました also mean "I came here myself", e.g. instead of sending someone / because someone was needed here and I knew that nobody else would come?

@DavideBordoni Yes, it can, e.g. 誰も来たがらなかったので自分で来ました.
